# Android - creating listview entirely from xml

Tags: android

I want to present some choices in my application.
Right now I'm doing it with buttons one under another.

What I really want to do is to present them as a list like in "Settings" application.
This boils down to creating a list with predefined values/choices.
My problem is that I can't figure out how to do it with xml.
I can add ListView to xml like this:

`<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>`

But how do I add entries to that?
All examples I've found do it programatically - through cursor adapters or array adapters.

How do I create a list of textViews using XML only n Android?
Does anyone know how it's done in "Settings" application and alike?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> But how do I add entries to that? All
>   examples I've found do it
>   programatically - through cursor
>   adapters or array adapters.

Use the `android:entries` attribute on your `ListView` element, pointing to a `<string-array>` resource (typically put in `res/values/arrays.xml`).

Comment: Thanks!
Is there a way to use views as entries? For example I want every entry to be image + textView + possibly checkbox.

Comment: @Leonti: Well, yes, but you have to "do it programatically - through cursor adapters or array adapters".